# In speech, what is the purpose of restating the form of address of the person one is addressing?

Tags: grammatical-roles

For instance, during [a debate held on 27 July 1891](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/1891-07-27/debates/411cc5a3-0fab-42b5-af41-1880e94429ef/MrAtkinsonAndMrSpeaker) in the *House of Commons of the United Kingdom*, one member, Mr Atkinson, said the following:

> Mr. Speaker, **Sir,** may I very respectfully claim freedom of speech in
> order to call your attention to the Journals put before the House
> to-day, which contain a statement with reference to me which, if it
> were true, would make me ashamed of myself and my conduct as a Member
> of Parliament for the remainder of my days.

Another member, Mr Goschen, said:

> I am only expressing the feelings which obtain universally in every
> part of the House when I say that you, **Sir,** have shown courtesy
> and impartiality to all sides of the House and to every Member of the
> House. You, **Sir,** have been obliged to appeal to the House against
> a Member of this House and you have said it is intolerable that during
> the whole of last week you have had to complain of the conduct of the
> hon. Member. I venture to think it will be the universal feeling of
> the House that the protection which you have asked at our hands must
> be accorded to you, **Sir,** unanimously. Without wishing to bear
> hardly on the hon. Member, without wishing in any way to show towards
> him any animosity, I still think the House will be of opinion that
> what you have said, **Sir,** must be marked, and must be marked in
> such a manner that it may be known that you have the support of the
> House.

What part of speech does, "Sir", the restated form of address, constitute and what is its purpose?

Comment: Is this English-specific? I can imagine it happening with "Monsieur" in French and similar words in German and Italian at least.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, no, the question applies to other languages as well.

Comment: I hear insistence in both cases. Will ya listen up, yes? In the first, I'm trying to talk and not being heard: *very respectfully* claim *freedom of speech* in order to *call your attention*.

Comment: It's to get and hold the attention of the addressee. If somebody speaking near you uses your name, you're more likely to pay attention.

Comment: It's a politeness marker (although often used ironically/sarcastically), and often fulfils the additional pragmatic roles of refocusing on the person addressed in the screed, and compartmentalising the over-lengthy sentences politicians are fond of. I suppose that some would compare ' ... opinion that what you have said, **Sir**, must be marked ...' with the vocative in ' ... opinion that what you have said, **Sid**, must be marked ...' and class 'Sir' as a noun.

Comment: @JohnLawler, that may be the reason in many other cases, but hardly when speaking in the Parliament (where one wants to get attention of many people other than the Speaker, and only pretends, as a matter of convention, to be addressing the Speaker).

Comment: Politeness has its own rules, especially in artificially archaic environments like Parliament.

Comment: Would this be declined as vocative if this were Latin?

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, get and hold the attention of the speaker. That said, certain venues have their lingo: Gentleman from Virginia, Gentlewoman from Kentucky. Though I'm partial to those who sound like hicks from the holler, I do enjoy forays into specialty speaks. But if you want an antithetical tone to the UK Parliament, just take a gander at Julia GIllard's diatribe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCNuPcf8L00 Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

In English the word "you" may be either singular or plural. The form "you, sir" makes it clear that only a single (male) person is being addressed rather than several people.

The noun following "you" can refer to one person or to several people, for example "You, John, have won the door prize", or "You, 9B, have been making too much noise". In this last example "9B" would be a school class of 15-year-olds.

These days it would be more common to begin with the noun, as in "John, you have won the door prize".

As for the first example, Australian Members of Parliament would more commonly say something like "Mr Speaker, may I ...". I don't know whether this would be the case in the UK Parliament. Adding "sir" makes the speech more formal, and emphasises the respect that parliamentarians are required to show to the Speaker of the House.

Comment: Don't forget this was 1891, when modes of address were more formal!

Comment: @KateBunting, indeed, and parliamentary speeches are even more formal than normal speech.